# С заглавной или строчной буквы?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Мой вопрос о правильном написании выражений:

*тема **В**еликой российской революции...*
и
*тема **Р**оссийской революции...*

Как правильно: с заглавной или со строчной буквы?

Comment: А что за революция?  И желателен контекст.

Answer (score 2):

[Революция 1917 года в России | Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

**Русская революция (Великая русская революция)** — условное название революционных событий, произошедших в России в 1917 году, начиная со свержения монархии во время **Февральской революции,** когда власть перешла к Временному правительству, которое, в свою очередь, было свергнуто в результате **Октябрьской революции большевиков**, провозгласивших советскую власть.

Это политическое движение  **с конкретной датировкой событий** является  **именем собственным** и пишется с прописной буквы, как и **Октя́брьская револю́ция** (полное официальное название в СССР — **Вели́кая Октя́брьская социалисти́ческая револю́ция**).